# Using L1 penalty in XGBoost

Tags: xgboost, regularization

I'm trying to use L1 regularization to select features in XGBoost classifier. However, I don't see any example code on how to specify the penalty of l1.

This is how I do in sklearn's LogisticRegression.

```
C = [10, 1, .1, .001]

for c in C:
    clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', C=c)
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print('C:', c)
    print('Training accuracy:', clf.score(X_train, y_train))
```

How should I specify penalty and C in XGBoost?

Comment: Check the minute 6' 40'' of this video where the presenter explains the regularizations in XGBoost: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CWwwtEM2TA&t=18s

Answer (score 5):

L2 and L1 regularization are controlled via the `lambda (=reg_lambda)` and `alpha (=reg_alpha)` parameter respectively. Higher values of `alpha` mean more L1 regularization. See the documentation [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest///parameter.html#parameters-for-tree-booster).

Comment: Hi, so if we are using alpha, we don't have to say penalty='l1', correct?

Comment: that's right...